# Is there an in-memory SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, unit-testing, amazon-sns, in-memory

im currently looking for a framework that provides a Rest-Api of a SNS and runs in-memory. That means no docker containers which sadly dont let me use localstack. I already searched everything and only find two old projects that are not usable because of security reasons.

What i found and can't use:

- https://github.com/gilbertojrequena/bonsai-sns - to old and clashes with log4j
- https://github.com/daflockinger/unitstack - to old has many vulnerabilities
- Localstack - Runs in Docker and i need a non Docker alternative

Comment: What is your purpose for looking for one?

Comment: To be able to test the whole production chain without having to mock a specific request. Basically to simulate production behaviour